# Datetime.ParseExact "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error

Tags: c#, datetime

Why i can't parse a string like this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("‎23.‎02.‎2016 08:59:35", 
                  "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It is throwing an exception

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I really don't understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some zero-width Unicode characters in your strings. If you remove them it will work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23.02.2016 08:59:35",
    "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Clean using a regex:

```
Regex.Replace("‎23.‎02.‎2016 08:59:35", @"[^\d\s\.:]", string.Empty)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But actually this string comes from somewhere else and i need to remove zero-width Unicode characters from it program programmatically. How can i do this ?

Comment: @EliArbel can I ask you how did you find out there are zero width characters in the strings? It is very curious for me, great answer anyway!

Comment: I am comparing the OP and the answer, and I don't see the differences in the two date time strings

Comment: There are tools to analyze unicode text characters online

Answer (score 1):

Beware beware the `&nbsp` non-breaking-space it looks like a space but isn't. You might have one of these between your date and time.... Especially if your pulling from a html document...Ohh the pain, the pain. The non-breaking-space also gets treated as whitespace in a regex and pass through undetected.

```
text = text.Replace('\u00A0',' ');
```

Comment: The actual "strange" character in the original string was a LTR unicode mark (0x200E) after each dot in the date