# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. : Error only in Server

Tags: c#, datetime

A Datetime Parse Error Occur in Server which is not in localhost,may  because of difference in timezone on localhost and Server , 
Code :
I am trying  24 hr time format to 12 hr(With AM and PM)

```
 string timesx2 = hr2[0]+":" + hr2[1];  //     19:22
 string s2 = DateTime.ParseExact(timesx2, "HHmm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    .ToString("hh:mm tt"); // output in localhost is: 7.22 PM
```

Comment: Try to use `FindSystemTimeZoneById` in c# and convert your datetime.

Comment: have you tried `ParseExact` with `"HH:mm"`?

Comment: @MykolaKovalchuk yes sir , i tired with HH:mm

Comment: @summerGhost i am working in Indian timezone and server is in US how should i use FindSystemTimeZoneById

Comment: @Akuria Convert IST time to UTC time first, then use "Indian standard time" in `FindSystemTimeZoneById` to Convert UTC time to IST.

Comment: @summerGhost 2017-01-01 01:15 stored in timesx how covert  this into UTC time

Answer (score 0):

You should use invariant culture (if you don't need to convert to your timezone of course)

```
    string timesx2 =hr2[0] + ":" + hr2[1];  //     19:22
    string s2 = DateTime.ParseExact(timesx2, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // output in localhost is: 7.22 PM
```

and it'l be ok in Indian culture.

Comment: string s2 = DateTime.ParseExact(timesx2, "HH:mm", null).ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); i also tried this one

Comment: The same issue also happens while i convert the 12 hr to 24 hr  **DateTime StartTimein12 = Convert.ToDateTime(StartTimes[0].StartTime[i]);
                            string CovertedTime = (StartTimein12.ToString("HH:mm"));
                             StartTimeDB = StartDates[0].StartDate[i] + " " + CovertedTime;**

Comment: have you tried to prefix the date to the string and parse it? `string timesx2 ="2017-01-01 " + hr2[0] + ":" + hr2[1];  //     19:22
            string s2 = DateTime.ParseExact(timesx2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
               .ToString("hh:mm tt"); // output in localhost is: 7.22 PM `

Comment: yes  i tired but not working in server all these codes are running fine in local host

Comment: please try to redefine your problem then - add the exact error description, maybe logs from server, etc...

Comment: i am trying to take a date with 24 hr time from database and display it in 12 hr format value is stored as ** 2017-07-12 01:15:00.000 ** how can i take the time from this and display in 12 hr which will run on every timezone

Comment: if the date from database is DateTime type - then it is a trivial task, otherwise (if it is string) - you should know exactly in which format it is written. I don't see the problem with the code you've presented and in my answer, the problem is in input data (`hr2`) probably...

Comment: 2017-01-01 01:15 the value in timesx2  while debugging is 2017-01-01 01:15   hr2[0]= "01" hr[2] ="15" @Roman

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740883/datetime-parseexact-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-error?rq=1  ?

Comment: i tried , sir can this is  may be because of difference in timezone in localhost and server , i am working in india and server is somewhere in US

Comment: converting DateTime to/from string doesn't depend on timezone it depends on culture

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing string is missing a colon.

Your composed time string is of format `HH:mm` while you try to parse a string composed of `HHmm`. That will not work.

Also remove the second `h` from the output format string if you want single digit hours to happen. Otherwise the output will be 07:22 PM.

```
 string timesx2 = hr2[0]+":" + hr2[1];  //     19:22
 string s2 = DateTime.ParseExact(timesx2, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("h:mm tt"); // output in localhost is: 7:22 PM
```

Comment: Did you verify that your array is containg properly formatted values? e.g. that there really are exactly 2 numeric characters in the array values and that they are within the time margin for hours and minutes respectively? Because that code here works when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

> Uppercase "H" indicates a 24-hour time and lowercase "h" indicates
>   12-hour time and will respect the AM/PM in the candidate string.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("3/21/2015 8:56:04 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your localtime to UTC time

```
DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDatetime); //Convert sent datetime to UTC.
```

Get Timezone information from zone name. Get Zone name from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx)

```
TimeZoneInfo zoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneName);
DateTime finalDatetime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcTime, zoneInfo);
```